# clj-time.coerce to-timestamp removes ms

Tags: datetime, clojure

This is my code but this removes the milliseconds part. How can I prevent it from doing that?

```
#(to-timestamp (from-time-zone (from-sql-time %) (time-zone-for-id "America/Detroit")))
```

I am using `clj-time`

Comment: Looking at [the](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/blob/d61cee60b10b226fc42f76a0395c5ab5a586206c/src/clj_time/coerce.clj#L98) [code](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/blob/d61cee60b10b226fc42f76a0395c5ab5a586206c/src/clj_time/coerce.clj#L54) it's round-tripping `java.sql.Timestamp` represented in milliseconds. It works fine when I test it, up to three digits of ms precision. Can you post what your input `%` value looks like?

Comment: (from-string "2017-08-28 10:58:22.053") @TaylorWood

I really think to-timestamp is the one causing the missing ms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `from-string` the formatter might be removing the ms when it parses the string.